# Call Chrome from C# applications

Tags: c#, windows, google-chrome

I am trying to call chrome from a C# application by sending messages o its window.

I have tried the solutions presented here [C# - Sending messages to Google Chrome from C# application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147929/c-sending-messages-to-google-chrome-from-c-application) without any luck and also using this http://www.mmowned.com/forums/other-mmos/warhammer-online/186390-sendinput-example-c.html.

Using "Come_WidgetWin_0" as the window name lets me switch correctly to the chrome window but the focus is still not properly on the main window.

When I send key presses, then nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/SendKeys.aspx). It is not Chrome specific, but it doesn't need to be. It shows how to send key strokes to another application and should work with Chrome.

Comment: Not claiming to be a Chrome expert... I do think that Chrome was specifically designed to sandbox its tabs from the outside world (using separate low-privilege processes). I wouldn't be too surprised if this meant Chrome's tab process is "shielded" from any key messages you might try to send it...

Comment: @Branko - I am not sure either. I just thought maybe that article would help. You may be right though.