# C++ Open a file to get dialog then How to navigate to certain tab?

Tags: winapi

Using [ShellExecute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9115574/how-can-you-open-a-file-with-the-program-associated-with-its-file-extension), I can open specify file then i get a system dialog like this:

[image]

Can I use the code to activate to the 3rd tab? (something like sendkey (ctrl+tab))?

the reason is i want to open this button:

[image]

**Update:**
I used the code from this [post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/bb2e9030-8cc5-4c21-874c-9c45f13f3887/c-sendkeys-navigate-through-a-page-using-the-tab-button?forum=vclanguage), however it doesn't work :

```
void SendKey(HWND hWndTargetWindow, BYTE virtualKey)
{
    keybd_event(virtualKey, 0, 0, 0);
    keybd_event(virtualKey, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
}

ShellExecute(0, 0, L"myfile.xxx", 0, 0, SW_SHOW);
HWND mywindow = FindWindow(0,L"caption.xxx");
//SetForegroundWindow(mywindow );   
std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(500));
SendKey(mywindow , VK_CONTROL);
SendKey(mywindow , VK_TAB);
```

but this work,  :

```
ShellExecute(0, 0, L"myfile.xxx", 0, 0, SW_SHOW);
HWND mywindow = FindWindow(0,L"caption.xxx");
//SetForegroundWindow(mywindow );   
std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(500));
SendKey(mywindow , 'A');
SendKey(mywindow , 'B');
```

[image]

Did I miss something?

Comment: This is a winapi question, much more than c++

Comment: You can use SHOpenPropSheetW (although it's marked as deprecated, it's not that easy to reproduce what it does...)  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlobj/nf-shlobj-shopenpropsheetw the optional last parameter is tab's name

Comment: Hi @SimonMourier, I have updated the post, maybe it is very close. I tried searching for SHOpenPropSheetW from your suggestion but couldn't find a sample to mimic because I'm unfamiliar with its arguments.  can you give me an example?

Comment: Something like this https://pastebin.com/raw/Y6ukWcVz

Comment: Hi @SimonMourier, your code works fine. my problem is need to run the file before activating the tab, Is it possible to use `SHCreateItemFromParsingName to trigger an open dialog`? (this file has been assigned default app to open). so can I use it like this? `SHCreateItemFromParsingName(L"c:\\temp\\zzz.txt", 1, IID_PPV_ARGS(&item));` then 1 argument will automatically run file by default app and bind to IShellItem

Comment: Hi @SimonMourier, think I still need ShellExecute or ShellExecuteInfo but don't know how to link the dialog to your sample code .

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. You want to start an app and then, what's the relation with this "system dialog". what is this? If you want to automate an application, then use UI automation, for ex:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30875408/get-titlebar-caption-of-any-application-using-microsoft-ui-automation

Comment: Hi @SimonMourier, Thanks you for your time. I will investigate this further.