# SendMessage WM_SETTEXT to another process fails because pointer received in target process is altered

Tags: c#, winapi, pinvoke

I'm currently working on automating a Win32 UI application that cannot be altered. So far my approach is using the standard message queue of the target application to inject my inputs. I've gotten quite far with that:

- "Clicking" buttons using `WM_COMMAND` works
- Reading the names of tabs via `TCM_GETITEMA` and activating them via virtual mouse clicks `WM_LBUTTONDOWN`/`WM_LBUTTONUP` works
- Reading enabled/disabled states of controls works

Where I'm stuck, however, is modifying the text of an editable ComboBox and its Edit control. I try using the `WM_SETTEXT` message like so:

```cs
    public static void SetText(IntPtr hWnd, string text) {

        // Maximum item text buffer length
        const int MAX_LEN = 512;    

        // Get process
        uint ProcessId;
        WinAPI.GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd, out ProcessId);

        IntPtr process = WinAPI.OpenProcess(
            WinAPI.ProcessAccessFlags.VMOperation | WinAPI.ProcessAccessFlags.VMRead |
            WinAPI.ProcessAccessFlags.VMWrite | WinAPI.ProcessAccessFlags.QueryInformation,
            false, ProcessId
        );

        if( process == IntPtr.Zero )
            throw new Exception("Could not open process");

        // Allocate memory in remote process
        IntPtr farTextPtr = WinAPI.VirtualAllocEx(process, IntPtr.Zero, MAX_LEN, 
            WinAPI.AllocationType.Commit, 
            WinAPI.MemoryProtection.ReadWrite
        );

        try {                
                if( farTextPtr == IntPtr.Zero )
                    throw new Exception("Could not allocate memory in target process");

                IntPtr nearTextPtr, pData;
                int bytesRead;

                // Write item text to remote memory (Unicode!)
                nearTextPtr = Marshal.StringToHGlobalUni(text);                    
                WinAPI.WriteProcessMemory(process, farTextPtr, nearTextPtr, MAX_LEN, out bytesRead);
                Marshal.FreeHGlobal(nearTextPtr);

                // Just for debugging purposes, read it back to verify it was set properly
                pData     = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(MAX_LEN);
                WinAPI.ReadProcessMemory(process, farTextPtr, pData, MAX_LEN, out bytesRead);
                text = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(pData);
                Marshal.FreeHGlobal(pData);

                // Set the text
                int res = WinAPI.SendMessage(hWnd, Constants.WM_SETTEXT, IntPtr.Zero, farTextPtr);
                if( res != 1 ) throw new Exception("SendMessage WM_SETTEXT failed");
        } finally {
            // Free remotely allocated memory
            if( farTextPtr != IntPtr.Zero )
                WinAPI.VirtualFreeEx(process, farTextPtr, 0, WinAPI.FreeType.Release);

            WinAPI.CloseHandle(process);
        }
    }
```

This does not work! If I attach Spy++ to the target control I can see, that the message is received, but it is received with a different `wParam` than I specified in the call to `SendMessage`.

E.g. the call to `VirtualAllocEx` returned a pointer within the target process of value `0x048b0000`. In the received message within Spy++ I see the value `0x0011AA88` which is wrong:

```
<000009> 0004065E S WM_SETTEXT lpsz:0011AA88 ("<random characters here>") [wParam:00000000 lParam:0011AA88]
```

Does the pointer somehow get altered? I do the same procedure in my routine to retrieve strings from controls, like with the TabControl. There it works flawlessly. Is there something different when using `WM_SETTEXT`?

Comment: You should use UI Automation techniques (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/ui-automation/ui-automation-overview) for that kind of work.At least it will let you try what you can and cannot do to another process.

Comment: Interesting. Could you provide an example for this case, please?

Comment: google is your friend. Here on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30875408/get-titlebar-caption-of-any-application-using-microsoft-ui-automation or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29951432/is-it-possible-to-activate-a-tab-in-another-program-using-an-intptr

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, `WM_SETTEXT` is a standard Windows message and the OS will take care of copying the data to the target process.  You must pass a pointer which is valid in your own process.

Comment: Wow that was an easy fix... The whole thing is reduced to 3 lines of code.

Comment: @sonntam - I'm having a similar problem here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50233894/sendmessage-for-wm-settext-returning-issue? .  Can you elaborate on your 3 lines of code?  I'm pretty sure i know, but want to make sure...I'm way down the rabbit hole here.

Answer (score 2):

For the combo, you should use the appropriate CB message from this list:

[ComboBox Control Messages](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff485901.aspx)

If the combo is owner drawn, it could be tricky to get the item text, but not impossible. `CB_GETITEMDATA` will usually return a pointer to some structure you can inspect with `ReadProcessMemory()`.

For `CB_GETLBTEXT` and `WM_SETTEXT`/`WM_GETTEXT`, you do not need to use `VirtualAllocEx()` and `(Read|Write)ProcessMemory()`. You can pass regular local pointers and the OS will marshal them between processes. You only need to use the `(Read|Write)ProcessMemory()` APIs to follow pointers more than one hop (as with structures that might be returned from `CB_GETITEMDATA` if the combo is owner drawn).